# Can we make a package as serializable

Tags: java, serialization, interface

We implement `java.io.Serializable` when our class is acting as model class/passing on network and generally we keep all these classes as one package (Say model). Instead of implementing each class, why can't we make a package can be serialize-able?. Anyways we no need to worry about implementations as its a marker interface. `I am thinking to make something like "auto-scan in spring"`.

**Edit**
com.mycorepackage.model is package where i have all POJO classes which are mapped to ORM (hibernate) and all classes here are `java.io.Serializable`. I want to make any class from this package is java.io.Serializable without declaring in each class. THINKING out of the box.

Comment: Packages are a logical way to organize the classes. There is no way you can make all the classes of a package serializable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in java since the technical feasibility is questionable.

- Where would you write the code that communicates the message 'All classes in this package will implement `Serializable`'.
- What happens when you include other jars that contain the same package but different classes ?

There is one way to implement it at the IDE level. Write a plugin that provides a menu option similar to `Right Click -> Source -> Organize Imports` on eclipse. That option organizes the imports for all classes under a tree. You can do something similar for classes that are of interest to you. Although I doubt the option would be widely used, it solves your problem.

Comment: The technical feasibility isn't 'questionable', it is nil. There is no syntax for it, period.

Comment: It communicates that it is 'questionable'. That's not the same as communicating that it is infeasible.

Comment: Starting a sentence with 'There is no way to do this' is good enough for most people to take a hint.